# Yii CMultiFileUpload Restrict Image width

Tags: php, yii

Is it possible to restrict image width E.g width not less than 500px in CMultiFileUpload


 Note: I am not referring to Image maxSixe or minSize;


 I mean something similar to this in Yii

```
$image_info = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$image_width = $image_info[0];
$image_height = $image_info[1];
```

This is my CMultiFileUpload file field.

```
<?php
      $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
         'model'=>$model,
         'name'=>'image',
         'attribute'=>'image',
         'accept'=>'jpeg|jpg|gif|png',
         'denied'=>'Only jpg,gif and png are allowed', 
         'max'=>4,
        'remove'=>'[x]',
        'duplicate'=>'Already Selected',
        ));
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set size in onFileSelect function

```
   $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', 
    array(
'name' => 'property_floor_plans',
'model' => $model,                    
'max' => $fimgCount,
'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png', // useful for verifying files
'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', // useful, i think
'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
'htmlOptions' => array('style' => "margin-left:15px;$options"),
                'options' => array(
                    'onFileSelect'=>'function(e ,v ,m){
                        var fileSize = e.files[0].size;
                        fileSize = (fileSize/1024);                           
                        if(fileSize>imgLimit){ 
                            alert("Exceeds file upload limit 2MB");                                
                            return false;
                        }                      
                        return true;
                    }',                        
                )
                ));
```